# Finding combinations from a list of numbers to reach a given sum WITHOUT repeats of the input numbers

Tags: math

I am trying to find a way to have a list of numbers be calculated to show all combinations that add up a desired sum WITHOUT repeating any of the input numbers after they've been used once, just consider it removed.

Example:

Input: 2, 5, 5, 10, 15, 10
Desired Sum: 20
Combinations: [10+10] [5+15]

So the left over numbers are just 2 and 5, since it can't repeat the already used numbers, so it can't say [5+5+10]

The problem I am having while searching for this function, even here on Stackoverflow, is that I can find a million working solutions that allow for repeat, but absolutely none that prevent repeats of the INPUT numbers (I can find some that disallow repeats of the combinations, but that doesn't so what I need it to do, and due to having many repeated input numbers, there inevitably will be repeats of combinations)

My purpose is that I need to group a large set of numbers (potentially hundreds of whole values between 5 and 14) into packs of 40 with no repeat of the input numbers.

Here's an example of the inputs I would like to use right now

`[5,9,5,5,6,7,8,7,5,6,8,8,7,5,7,5,7,5,5,8,8,8,9,5,8,6,5,8,8,8,5,6,9,6,9,8,7,5,9,5,6,8,5,5,5,7,7,6,8,7,8,6,9,6,6,6,8,5,6,6,6,5,8,6,6,6,8,9,10,10,10,10,14,14,13,13,8,6,7,7,12,12,12,11,11,12,12,12,5,10,5,6,6,11,6,6,9,10,6,13,6,5,8,7,8,5,6,6,8,6,5]`

And have that list show all possible combinations of 40 without using each value more than once.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: list (5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 15) gives or [5,5,10][5,15] or [10,10][5,15] sets. Do you want to generate both?

Comment: No, I want the set of input numbers to only use each value once, efficiency (finding the most possible combinations) is nice, but not required. I just need all combinations that sum to 40, removing each input number after it's been used.

Answer (score 0):

Simple (not very fast) method:

```
Repeat:
Find the first set with needed sum 
Remove it's elements from the list   
    Repeat:
    Check if similar set still exists // it's very likely for limited number range
    Remove it's elements from the list
```